# Arithmetic operators as variables javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, operators

```
var x = 10;
var y = 5;
var action = '+';
var z = x action y; //15
```

is it possible to assign Arithmetic operators as variables?

Comment: Maybe with some preprocessing. In other words, when serving for web you could use server side scripting to transform the javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

You could just check for the actions you wanna be supporting:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 5;
var action = '+';
var z = null;
if (action == '+') {
    z = x + y;
} else if (action == '-') {
    z = x - y;
} else if (action == '*') {
    z = x * y;
} else if (action == '/') {
    z = x / y;
} else {
    alert('Unsupported action');
}
```

There's also the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function which allows you to execute some dynamic javascript statement but its use is often frowned upon:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 5;
var action = '+';
var z = window.eval(x + action + y);
```

Comment: a switch case might be neater

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible using that syntax. The simplest way to do it is to make `action` a function:

```
var action = function(a, b) { return a + b; };
...
var z = action(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.eval(x + action + y);
```

Comment: While this is correct, it sould also be pointed out that [Eval is Evil](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/), and why it should be used with caution.